# D3js Geo unzoom element when zoom map

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, geo

I have a D3js map built with topojson.js.

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
```

Everything works fine, but I am looking for an effect that I cannot manage to achieve. When, zooming the map I would like the pins over it to scale down, But if I scale it down, I need to recalculate their coordinates and I can't find the formula to do so.

Zoom handler

```
scale = d3.event.scale;
if (scale >= 1) { 
   main.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")
   scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}    
else {
   main.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(1)");
}

//43x49 is the size initial pine size when scale = 1 
var pins = main.select("#pins").selectAll("g").select("image")
            .attr("width", function () {
                return 43 - (43 * (scale - 1));
            })
            .attr("height", function () {
                return 49 - (49 * (scale - 1));
            })
            .attr("x", function () {
                //Calculate new image coordinates;
            })
            .attr("y", function () {
                //Calculate new image coordinates;
            });
```

**My question is : how do I calculate x and y based on new scale?**

I hope I am clear enough.

Thanks for your help

EDIT :

Calculation of initial pins coordinates :

```
"translate(" + (projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0] - 20) + "," 
+ (projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1] - 45) + ")"
```

-20 and -45 to have the tip of the pin right on the target.

Comment: Could you show how you are calculating the initial ping positions? If the pins are inside `main` (which I assume is a `g` or `svg` element), then you shouldn't need to change `x` and `y` at all when you `scale` the the container. Also, you might want to set the [scaleExtent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#scaleExtent) instead of manually checking for `scale >= 1`. That would give you a better behavior as well (i.e. no hysteresis in zooming if the user zooms out too much).

Comment: You are right, everything is in main. and the pins work fine on zoom but they get too big, so I would like to scale them down on zoom. But I don't know how to recalculate the coordinates after "counter-scale".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "counter-scale" the pins, i.e. as `main` scales up/down you need to scale the pins down/up, in the opposite direction. The counter-scale factor is `1/scale`, and you should apply it to each of the `<g>`s containing the pin image. This lets you remove your current width and height calculation from the `<image>` nodes (since the parent `<g>`'s scale will take care of it).

However, for this to work properly, you'll also need to remove the `x` and `y` attributes from the `<image>` and apply position via the counter-scaled parent `<g>` as well. This is necessary because if there's a local offset (which is the case when x and y are set on the `<image>`) that local offset gets scaled as the parent `<g>` is scaled, which makes the pin move to an incorrect location.

So:

```
var pinContainers = main.select("#pins").selectAll("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var x = ... // don't know how you calculate x (since you didn't show it)
        var y = ... // don't know how you calculate y
        var unscale = 1/scale;
        return "translate(" + x + " " + y + ") scale(" + unscale + ")";
    })
pinContainers.select("image")
    .attr("width", 43)
    .attr("height", 49)
    // you can use non-zero x and y to get the image to scale
    // relative to some point other than the top-left of the
    // image (such as the tip of the pin)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the group "counter-scale". I did not specify x and y as it is what I am looking for. I edited my question to remove confusion.